# How to save selection id's from listview

Tags: android, arrays, xml, listview, android-listview

I have an activity that contains a submit button and a multiple select listview that I populate with a string-array, this array exists in both english and french.

strings.xml

```
    <string-array name="trucks">
       <item name="truck1">Mini-van</item>
       <item name="truck2">Pick-up</item>
       <item name="truck3">4 x 4</item>
    </string-array>
```

strings_fr.xml

```
    <string-array name="trucks">
       <item name="truck1">Mini-van french</item>
       <item name="truck2">Pick-up french</item>
       <item name="truck3">4 x 4 french</item>
    </string-array>
```

Once the user selects which ever items he/she wants they hit a button to save the selections(locally to an array). I am able to get the string content of the selected items but if i save those then it would be saving the language specific values. what I need is the name or some sort of id (truck1, truck2) to save so that the next time the list is loaded I can pragmatically check off the saved list items regardless of language, as well as send the vehicle id's to the server when it comes time to permanently save the data.

Below is what I have so far..

activity_truck_picker.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_truck_done"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/themedButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Add Truck(s)" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lst_trucks"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_truck_done"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TruckPickerActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TruckPickerActivity extends Activity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Presite";

    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_truck_picker);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_trucks);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_truck_done);

        String[] trucks = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.trucks);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, trucks);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
            int position = checked.keyAt(i);
            if (checked.valueAt(i))
                selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
        }

        String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
            Log.i(TAG, "Truck Selected: " + selectedItems.get(i));

            String itemName = ...; // Some how look up name of string in array for storing in database

        }
    }
}
```

I cant figure out a way to get the names/id of the selected options for saving.
 Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onItemClickListener` to your `ListView`, where the `long id` parameter is the id of the item that has been clicked:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        //Do something with id parameter

    }
});
```

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to get the `name` attribute of your string array declared in xml. I'd create a 2nd array holding the name of your 1st array, and fetch the names using the id or position parameter from `onItemClickListener()`

Comment: Seems kind of stupid to have to maintain another array to do something like this but it works, thanks.